# Can somebody give me an eagle eye perspective on Magento blocks, layout and templates?

Tags: magento

Can somebody give me an eagle eye perspective on Magento blocks, layout and templates and how they relate to each other?

I understood that blocks are the basic building-blocks that a page is made of and that they are kind of mini-controllers.

I also understood that layout brings these blocks somehow together.

But there is still some uncertainty about templates and how they relate to blocks and layouts and vice versa.

Comment: check the updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blocks are the building modules of a page. They can be treated as "bricks". Now every block comes inside a layout. Layout is used to define the "shape" of the page. Now templates are used to define the behaviour of a particular block. That means each block or "brick" will have different charateristic depend upon the template it is used.

That is, to construct a magento page, you need to define a layout first that will give you an idea of shape of that page. Now you fill the layout with blocks. Each blocks now concentrate on a particular section of the entire layout. That means depending upon the "nature" of block, each small section will behave differently. To define the unique nature of a particular section, blocks uses templates (templates actually holds the webpage building codes, ie html + js + php)

I hope that will give you a short idea.

Try to google this. I am sure there are lot of lot of tutorials, blogs available about this.

Answer (score 1):

**What are blocks?**

There are basically 4 things you need to know:

> There are two types of blocks: those that automatically render their
>   children and those that don't. Knowing which type you're using will
>   help you in debugging.
>
> Magento blocks are essentially models that contain logic for your view templates. Mind you - this is not business logic, but it is logic
>   related to the display of the information you're presenting. This is
>   by definition presentational logic. If you're familiar with Zend
>   Framework's Zend_Layout you could draw a comparison between custom
>   view objects and layout helpers.
>
> The template file assigned to a block object can execute code as if it is local to that object. That is, $this corresponds directly to
>   the block class.
>
> Layout actions are a thing that people use.

**Two types of blocks**

> There are two types of blocks at the end of the day - those that
>   render automatically and those that don't. Take notes because this is
>   on the Magento Certification exam!!

```
Auto-rendered blocks
```

> When defined in a layout, any block of type core/text_list will
>   automatically render all its children. While core/text will
>   automatically render itself it really only should contain text and
>   therefore is not useful for layout purposes (though some clever things
>   can be achieved with them).

Other blocks

> Any other block type will need to be rendered manually. Provide the
>   block an alias which can then be passed to getChildHtml, returning the
>   content which you then echo.

**Layouts And Templates**

> As the name suggests, layout files are useful in rendering front pages
>   of Magento. Layout files are XML files that reside in in app > design
>
> > frontend > your interface > your theme > layout. Here, you can see that there are many layout files for any given module. Each Magento
> >     module has its own layout files much like the customer module has the
> >     customer.xml layout file, catalog module have catalog.xml layout file
> >     etc. These layout files contain structural blocks and content blocks.

read the following blogs. it will clear your concepts for magneto.

http://alanstorm.com/category/magento

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/magefordev/mage-for-dev-4.html

http://blog.philwinkle.com/the-most-misunderstood-concept-in-magento/

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/custom-layouts-and-templates-with-magento--cms-21419

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Thanks: Each Block is tied to a single Template file. Inside a phtml file, PHP's $this keyword will contain a reference to the Template's Block object.

Comment: link only answers are not good.. it would be better if you put a short description about this topic.

Comment: @RajeevKTomy : take care from next time.